# If a String contains a certain letter an exact amount of times

Tags: java, string

In Java, is there a way of saying .. for example "Does this word contain a Z three times?"

I'm guessing there could be some clever char value?

```
String word = "pizzaz"

// Check if word contains three z's
boolean b = word.contains("SOME CLEVER CHAR VALUE??");
```

If possible, could an integer value be used when passing through the "amount of times" i.e.

`int letterAmount = 3;`

Comment: Yes. No. Regex is a possibility

Comment: Why has this been voted down?

Comment: Not my downvote, but presumably because you show no attempt...

Comment: discrimination against people with low reputation ;)

Comment: No. Displeasure at seeing no attempt shown.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java regex match count](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378451/java-regex-match-count)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a regex to do that. Following your example:

```
word.matches(".*(z.*){3}.*")
```

it returns true if your string has 3 z's.

Comment: split the string and concatnate with the variables: word.matches(".*(" + charVar +".*){" + numVar + "}.*")

Comment: can i pass a special character like ?, I tried that, and it gives me an error.

Answer (score 5):

A somewhat expensive and roundabout way to count single-character matches is as follows:

```
String s = "pizzaz";
int numMatches = s.length() - s.replaceAll("z", "").length();
```

When the length of the string with all `"z"`s removed is subtracted from the length of the original string, you end up with the number of `z`s in the original string.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/):

```
boolean hasThreeZs = StringUtils.countMatches("pizzaz", "z") == 3;
```

or using Spring's version of [StringUtils](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/StringUtils.html)

```
boolean hasThreeZs = StringUtils.countOccurrencesOf("pizzaz", "z") == 3;
```

Comment: For what `StringUtils`? There is no such package in the JDK

Comment: @fge From the apache commons API

Comment: @fge true, but there should be :)

Comment: Ok so letterAmount would be two in that case. I meant how could I then pass letterAmount into the .contains("INCLUDES letterAmount") bit

Comment: Typo fixed, just check the `letterAmount` returned.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of the string, another option is to just walk through the string, counting characters:

```
public static boolean contansCharCount(String s, char targetC, int targetCount) {
  char[] sArray = s.toCharArray();

  int actualCount = 0;

  for(char c : sArray)
    actualCount = (c == targetC) ? actualCount + 1 : actualCount;

  return (actualCount == targetCount);
}
```

This takes O(N) time.

Answer (score 0):

```
String word = "pizzaz";    
System.out.println(word.replaceAll("[^z]","").equals("zzz"));
```