# How to find how many times does a string object repeat in java?

Tags: java, string, object

I have to String objects:

```
String first = "/Some object that has a loop in it object/";
String second = "object";
```

What I need to do is find how many times does the second object repeat in the first object, can you please show me how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `indexOf` in a loop, advancing the starting index each time that you find the word:

```
int ind = 0;
int cnt = 0;
while (true) {
    int pos = first.indexOf(second, ind);
    if (pos < 0) break;
    cnt++;
    ind = pos + 1; // Advance by second.length() to avoid self repetitions
}
System.out.println(cnt);
```

This will find the word multiple times if a word contains self-repetitions. See the comment above to avoid such "duplicate" finds.

[Demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/PuI86M).

Comment: Thank you, this did everything as necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Use this single line which utilizes regular expressions in the background:

```
String[] parts = first.split(second);
```

String `second` occurs **(parts.length - 1)** times in  String `first`. That's all.

**EDIT:**

To prevent unwanted results that could occur in the case of String `second` might contain regex-specific characters, you can use `Pattern.quote(second)` when passing it to `split()` method, as one of the commentators suggested.

Comment: I would recommend using `Pattern.quote` in the split - who knows what's in the second `String`.

Comment: @bmorris591 can you give an example of my code's probable bug?

Comment: If the second string contains some regex, for example $ or ( or [, then the split will interpret the regex and return really odd things or maybe even throw an exception.

Comment: @bmorris591 thank you bro for enlightment. see my edit, please.

Comment: `split(re)` by default removes empty strings at the end of the array, which will cause this method to give wrong result. You need to use `split(re, -1)` to preserve them.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`regex`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), example:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hello = "HelloxxxHelloxxxHello"; //String you want to 'examine'
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Hello"); //Pattern string you want to be matched
        Matcher  matcher = pattern.matcher(hello); 

        int count = 0;
        while (matcher.find())
            count++; //count any matched pattern

        System.out.println(count);    // prints how many pattern matched
    }
}
```

source: [java regex match count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378451/java-regex-match-count)

Comment: Make sure you quote the regex, who knows what's in the second `String`.

Comment: For input "ababab" this returns 1, while indexOf based solutions returns 2.

Comment: @Betlista: Read the comment in the indexOf solution. `+1` finds overlapping matches. `+ needle.length()` finds non-overlapping matches. This method here finds non-overlapping matches

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
 String first = "/Some object that has a loop in it object/";
     String second = "object";
     Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(second);
     Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(first) ;
     long count = 0;
     while(matcher.find()) {
         count ++;

     }
     System.out.println(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

try like below...

```
String str = "/Some object that has a loop in it object/";
String findStr = "object";
int lastIndex = 0;
int count =0;

while(lastIndex != -1){

       lastIndex = str.indexOf(findStr,lastIndex);

       if( lastIndex != -1){
             count ++;
             lastIndex+=findStr.length();
      }
}
System.out.println(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either split the `String` on the second `String` and count the length of the resulting array, it will have one more element that that number of occurrences. Or you can use `Pattern` and `Matcher`, which is a slightly more proper approach.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {
    String first = "/Some object that has a loop in it object/";
    String second = "object";

    System.out.println(first.split(Pattern.quote(second)).length - 1);

    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(second));
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(first);
    int count = 0;
    while (matcher.find()) {
        count++;
    }

    System.out.println(count);

}
```

Don't forget to use `Pattern.quote` just in case.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older topic, but off the top of my head, you could use recursion:

```
// Recursive routine to find the xth repeat of a string
public int atIndex(String searchin, String searchfor, int whichone, int pos) {
    return atIndex(searchin, searchfor, whichone, pos, 0);
}

public int atIndex(String searchin, String searchfor, int whichone, int pos, int recursed) {
    return (whichone>0?atIndex(searchin, searchfor, --whichone, searchin.indexOf(searchfor,pos)+1,++recursed):(recursed==0?-1:pos-1));
}
```

I'm new at Java, so there may be a speed or resources issue that I'm not aware of, but a little bit of testing should suss out any problems.

To call it, you might use:

```
    String HL7Test="MSH|^~\\&|EPIC|EPICADT|SMS|SMSADT|199912271408|CHARRIS|ADT^A04|1817457" ;
    System.out.println(atIndex(HL7Test, "|", 4, 0));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The most precious resource in many programming languages is call stack. You can easily unfold this into a loop instead, which would make it more stable. Your code can hit, excuse the pun, a [stack overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow#Very_deep_recursion).

Answer (score 0):

Here you only need two variables and do all the checking in the loop condition.

```
int pos = 0;
int count= 0;
while (first.indexOf(second, pos) >= 0) {
    count++;
    pos = first.indexOf(second, pos) + 1;
}

System.out.println(count);
```