# How to make a regex to find if a string contains a placeholder like %1$s

Tags: java, regex

I failed after several tries to make a regex to find if a string contains a placeholder like %1$s or %3$d in a message like:

```
Hello, %1$s! You have %2$d new messages.
```

Can somebody give me, any help ?

How can I count how many placeholders are there ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this pattern:

```
Pattern.compile("^.*%[0-9]+\\$[sd].*");
```

To count all matches, you could use `Matcher` and count like this:

```
int count = 0;
while (matcher.find())
  count++;
```

I'm not sure there's a more efficient way.

Comment: I'll take your word :-) Glad it helped.

Comment: IF somebody reaches here and has to count the matches it may have to use this version:
    Pattern.compile("^*%[0-9]+\\$[sd]*");

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex in `String#matches` method call:

```
".*?%\\d+\\$[sd].*"
```

Code:

```
boolean found = string.matches( ".*?%\\d+\\$[sd].*" );
```

Answer (score 0):

This will capture both cases.  If you are using Java, I've provided a link on how to count matches.

(%1\$s|%2\$d)

[java-regex-match-count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378451/java-regex-match-count)

Comment: In lieu of changing my regex to look like the other posts, let me just say the other regex answers provided are good, since they are more generic.