# count directly repeated substring occurence

Tags: java, string, substring

I am trying to count the number of directly repeatings of a substring in a string.

```
String s = "abcabcdabc";
String t = "abc";
int count = 2;
```

EDIT:
because some people are asking, i try to clarify this: there are 3 times t in s but i need the number of times t is repeated without any other character. that would result in 2, because the d in my example is not the starting character of t. ('d' != 'a').

Another example to clarify this:

```
String s = "fooabcabcdabc";
String t = "abc";
int count = 0;
```

I know how to count the number of occurrences in the string, i need it to be repeating from left to right without interruption!

Here is what i have so far, but i think i made a simple mistake in it...

```
public static int countRepeat(String s, String t){
    if(s.length() == 0 || t.length() == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    int count = 0;
    if(t.length() == 1){
        System.out.println(s+" | " + t);
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) != t.charAt(0)){
                return count;
            }
            count++;
        }
    }else{
        System.out.println(s+" | " + t);
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            int tchar = (i- (count*(t.length()-1)));
            System.out.println(i+ " | " + tchar);
            if (s.charAt(i) != t.charAt(tchar)){
                return count;
            }
            if(tchar >= t.length()-1){
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

what am i doing wrong? And is there a better/faster way to do this?

Comment: You know, `String` has `.indexOf()`...

Comment: I know, but indexOf() is returning the first occurance which is at 0. Can you post a code example using indexOf() that is actually answering my question?

Comment: Well, `String` also has `.subString()` ;) I still don't understand, though, what you mean by " count the number of directly repeatings"?

Comment: in my example, if you count the number of occurences, it would result 3 but it should result 2 because the d is not part of the substring.

Comment: Uh, sorry, I still don't understand...

Comment: OK, what is "fooabc" supposed to return as a result?

Comment: "fooabc" will return 0

Comment: It shows 3 because the last `abc` is also a substring, even when it already passed `dabc`. It just continues from that and sees another `abc`.

Comment: You should use Regular Expressions. Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378451/java-regex-match-count

Comment: OK, see my answer, it should do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `indexOf()` makes the code much easier:

```
public static int startingRepeats(final String haystack, final String needle)
{
    String s = haystack;
    final int len = needle.length();

    // Special case...
    if (len == 0)
        return 0;

    int count = 0;

    while (s.startsWith(needle)) {
        count++;
        s = s.subString(len);
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Note, you could also use `.startsWith()` instead of `.indexOf()`

Comment: your code needs a check for len==0 because then you have an endless loop!

Answer (score 2):

There exists a [`str.indexOf(substring,index)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method in the String API.

In pseudocode this would mean something like this:

```
declare integer variable as index 
declare integer variable as count
while index <= (length of string - length of substring)
  index = indexOf substring from index
  if index >= 0
    increment count
  end if
end while
```

Comment: this will simply count the number of times substring is represented in str and is not checking for interruption.

Comment: Yes, it wasn't clear from your question what the actual problem was. I have to leave for class now but I will check back on this question later tonight and see whether help is still needed.

Answer (score 1):

This version does not allocate new objects (substrings, etc) and just look for the characters where they are supposed to be.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(countRepeat("abcabcabc", "abc")); //  3
    System.out.println(countRepeat("abcabcdabc", "abc")); // 2
    System.out.println(countRepeat("abcabcabcx", "abc")); // 3
    System.out.println(countRepeat("xabcabcabc", "abc")); // 0
}
public static int countRepeat(String s, String t){
    int n = 0; // Ocurrences
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i ++) { // i is index in s
        int j = i % t.length(); // corresponding index in t
        boolean last = j == t.length() - 1; // this should be the last char in t
        if (s.charAt(i) == t.charAt(j)) { // Matches?
            if (last) { // Matches and it is the last
                n++;
            }
        } else { // Do not match. finished!
            break;
        }
    }
    return n;
}
```

Comment: I have compared your solution to fges solution and his is around 7 times faster than yours! Seems that using native functions has some benefits...

Comment: I tried to write clean code and not fastest code but I expected this to be faster at least with this short strings and most of them being positive matches.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the another calculator:

```
String s = "abcabcdabc";
String t = "abc";

int index = 0;
int count = 0;

while ((index = s.indexOf(t, index)) != -1) {
    index += t.length();
    count++;
}

System.out.println("count = " + count);
```