# Comparing words

Tags: java, compare

I have problem with my code. I wrote program for count words in text, but I have small problem with patterns which must be search in text. Maybe somebody can help me.

```
import java.util.*;
```

`class KomparatorLicz implements Comparator<Word> {`

```
@Override
public int compare(Word arg0, Word arg1) {
return arg1.amount - arg0.amount;
}
```

`}`

`class KomparatorString  implements Comparator<Word> {`

```
@Override
public int compare(Word obj1, Word obj2) {
  if (obj1.content == obj2.content) {
      return 0;
  }
  if (obj1.content == null) {
      return -1;
  }
  if (obj2.content == null) {
      return 1;
  }
  return obj1.content.compareTo(obj2.content);
}
```

}

`class Word
{
    public String content;
    public int amount;`

```
public Word(String content, int amount) {
this.content = content;
this.amount = amount;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
return "Word [content=" + content + ", amount=" + amount + "]";
}
```

}

`public class Source4 {`

```
public static float procent(int wordCount, int oneWord)
{
return (((float)oneWord*100)/(float)wordCount);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
String line, wordsLine[];
    String klucze = null;
int valTemp;
int wordCount=0;
int keyWords=0;
HashMap<String, Word> slownik = new HashMap<String, Word>();
ArrayList<Word> lista= new ArrayList<Word>();
ArrayList<Object> keyWordsList = new ArrayList<Object>();
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String alph = in.nextLine();

keyWords = in.nextInt();

    for(int i=0; i<keyWords; i++)
    {
        klucze = in.next();
        keyWordsList.add(klucze);
    }



while(in.hasNextLine())
{       
   line = in.nextLine();

   if(line.equals("koniec")) break;

   wordsLine  = line.split("[^" + alph + "]");

   for(String s : wordsLine) {
       if(s != null && s.length() > 0) 
       {           
       wordCount++;
       if(slownik.containsKey(s))
       {
           valTemp = slownik.get(s).amount;
           slownik.remove(s);
           valTemp++;
           slownik.put(s, new Word(s,valTemp));
       }
       else
       {
           slownik.put(s, new Word(s,1));
       }
       }
    }
}

for (String key : slownik.keySet()) 
{
    lista.add(slownik.get(key));
}



Collections.sort(lista, new KomparatorString());

StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
int keyWordCounter=0;
int amountBuff=0;
float percentBuff=0;

for (int i = 0; i<lista.size();i++) 
{
    if(keyWordsList.contains(lista.get(i)))
    {
    result.append(amountBuff+" "+percentBuff+"%");
    amountBuff = 0;
    percentBuff = 0; 
    result.append("\n");
    result.append(lista.get(i).amount+" "+(procent(wordCount,lista.get(i).amount)+"%"));
    result.append(" "+lista.get(i).content);
    result.append("\n");
    keyWordCounter+=lista.get(i).amount;
    }
    else
    {
    amountBuff+=lista.get(i).amount;
    percentBuff+=procent(wordCount,lista.get(i).amount);
    }
}
result.append(amountBuff+" "+percentBuff+"%");
System.out.println("Wersja AK");
System.out.println(keyWords+" różnych słów kluczowych");
System.out.println(wordCount+" wystąpień wszystkich słów");
System.out.println(keyWordCounter+" "+procent(wordCount,keyWordCounter)+"% "+" wystąpień słów kluczowych");
System.out.println((wordCount-keyWordCounter)+" "+procent(wordCount,(wordCount-keyWordCounter))+"% wystąpień innych słów");
System.out.println(result);
}
```

`}`

Comment: Please post your code directly in your post, not an external link.

Comment: Can you clarify your goal?

Comment: Program must counts my patterns for example how many "ABDA" I have in text.

Comment: You can use Matcher see [answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378451/java-regex-match-count

Comment: I use ArrayList, but I don't know why program don't add my patterns on list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's wrong code `if(keyWordsList.contains(lista.get(i)))`.

You need `if(keyWordsList.contains(lista.get(i).content))`.