# Java For Loop Trouble, Index Errors

Tags: java, for-loop, indexoutofboundsexception

```
class Main{
    public static void main (String str[]) throws IOException{
      Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
      String message = scan.nextLine();
      String[] sWords = {" qey ", " $ "," ^^ "};
      int lenOfArray = sWords.length;
      int c = 0;  
      int[] count = {0,0,0};
```

Getting the error, "java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1" , in one of the for loops. I want the program to check for each substring in the sWord array and count how many times it occurs in the main message input.

```
  for (int x = 0; x < sWords.length; x++){
    for (int i = 0, j = i + sWords[x].length(); j < message.length(); i++){
      if ((message.substring(i,j)).equals(sWords[x])){
        count[c]++;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Use regex instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378451/java-regex-match-count

Comment: in your loop i is higher value than j and size of of message string so you get -1

Answer (score 0):

Following your approach, you need to set the value of `j`within the inner loop. Otherwise, it is only assigned on the first iteration. This changes the upper bound in the inner `for` loop as shown below. You also need to increment the counter index `c` after you search for an `sWord`.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main (String str[]) throws IOException {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String message = scan.nextLine();
        String[] sWords = {" qey ", " $ ", " ^^ "};
        int lenOfArray = sWords.length;
        int c = 0;
        int[] count = {0, 0, 0};
        for (int x = 0; x < sWords.length; x++) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= message.length()-sWords[x].length(); i++) {
                int j = i + sWords[x].length();
                if ((message.substring(i, j).equals(sWords[x]))) {
                    count[c]++;
                }
            }
            ++c;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find number of occurrences of each string in `sWords` in the code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    try {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String message = scan.nextLine();
        String[] sWords = {" qey ", " $ ", " ^^ "};
        int lenOfArray = sWords.length;
        int c = 0;
        int[] count = {0, 0, 0};
        for (int i = 0; i < lenOfArray; i++) {
            while (c != -1) {
                c = message.indexOf(sWords[i], c);
                if (c != -1) {
                    count[i]++;
                    c += sWords[i].length();
                }
            }
            c = 0;
        }
        int i = 0;
        while (i < lenOfArray) {
            System.out.println("count[" + i + "]=" + count[i]);
            i++;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It's better to use apache  commons lang StringUtils

```
int count = StringUtils.countMatches("a.b.c.d", ".");
```