# How do I search for a phrase in a string without looking for the word in the phrase multiple times

Tags: java, arrays, string, search

So I want to search for a argument a user inputs such as "Hello there" without looking for "Hello" and "There" its self.

```
String[] words = text.split("\\s+");        
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
         if (searchString.contains(words[i])){
             counter++;
         }
    }
```

Heres the code Im basically trying to count how many times a string appears in txt file.

Comment: Huh? "Hello there" is **two** words. Why are you `split`ing the text? `text.contains(searchString)`? Did you want to count the number of times `searchString` appears in `text`?

Comment: how does your text file look like? please show an example input and expected output.

Comment: yea I want to count the number of times the "Hello there" is placed together not individually through the text. Im splitting from white spaces, and yes I want t count how many times searchString shows up.

Comment: this is this the expected out put                                                          (java TextSearch "drops of blood" input.txt)                                      
output:
the snow, she pricked her finger, and there fell from it three drops of
blood on the snow. And when she saw how bright and red it looked, she
Total matches: 1

Comment: probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378451/java-regex-match-count

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use Pattern and Matcher.

```
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Hello there");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
  int counter = 0;
  while (m.find()) {
      counter++;
      System.out.println("found hello there!");
  }
```

Counter will reflect the number of matches found in the text.

(Answer edited to reflect clarification in comments)

Comment: The issue with this is that im trying to match with String[] words which is a array and not text. Im doing this because String[] words splits the white spaces of the text file.

Comment: You could do Arrays.toString(words) and then perform the matching.  Why do you need an array?

Comment: so i can use text.split

Answer (score 0):

**use Pattern, Matcher and autoincrement integer**

```
public static int stringCounter(String input, String toSearch)
{
     int counter = 0;
     Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(toSearch);
     Matcher  matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
     while (matcher.find()) counter++;
     return counter;
}
```