# Is there a way to verify a regular expression has exactly one match in Java?

Tags: java, regex

i'm currently making a regex generator for some invoices, and I wanted to know if there is a way to know that my regular expression matched with one and only one part of the text. The regular expr itself is not really important, I just want to know if I can check there was only one match and no more.
I'm of course using `Pattern` and `Matcher` from `java.util.regex` package.
I tried to use `matcher.groupCount()` but that doesnt seem to do the trick because it involves group count not the matches count.
  Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Would you consider `a+` to match "aa" more than once?

Comment: You could just use Matcher#find() twice. If the second time fails, then you only have one match.

Comment: What about [matcher.results().count()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58946704/9758194)?

Comment: @JvdV Didn't know about that, but it is only in Java 9+.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `String#matches` here with some lookahead logic:

```
String input = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";
if (input.matches("((?!\\bfox\\b).)*\\bfox\\b(?!.*\\bfox\\b).*")) {
    System.out.println("MATCH");
}
```

The above regex being used is (`String#matches` uses implicit starting/ending anchors):

```
^((?!\bfox\b).)*\bfox\b(?!.*\bfox\b).*$
```

This will match a single first occurrence of `fox`, provided that `fox` does not occur anywhere else later in the input string.

**Edit:**

The above answer can be made to work across lines by enabling dot all mode using the `(?s)` flag:

```
String input = "The quick brown\nfox jumps \tover the lazy dog.";
if (input.matches("(?s)((?!\\bfox\\b).)*\\bfox\\b(?!.*\\bfox\\b).*")) {
    System.out.println("MATCH");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, would this work on a multiline text ? I'm getting input from a large file and i'm searching amounts, In some case there is exactly one match  and my purpose is to determine when.

Comment: @R113 Yes, just add `(?s)` to the start of the regex pattern using in `String#matches`, and then it should still work in multiline mode.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate the matches and keep a count.

```
final Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("[fm]oo").matcher(",foo,moo,");

int numMatches = 0;
String match = null;
while (matcher.find()) {
    numMatches++;
    match = matcher.group();
}

if (numMatches > 1) {
    System.out.println("expected one match, found " + numMatches);
}
else {
    System.out.println(match);
}
```

If you don't care how many matches there are, you can put a condition in the loop and `break` as soon as you've found the 2nd one.

Or refactor to a util method. In this implementation, I presumed you didn't care about how many matches there are.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("[fm]oo").matcher(",foo,moo,");

    System.out.println(
        getSingleMatch(matcher)
             .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Expected exactly 1 match"))
             //or handle the failure however use you like
    );
}

private static Optional<String> getSingleMatch(Matcher matcher) {
    final boolean foundOnce = matcher.find();
    if (!foundOnce) return Optional.empty();
    final String firstMatch = matcher.group();
    final boolean foundTwice = matcher.find();
    return !foundTwice ? Optional.ofNullable(firstMatch) : Optional.empty();
}
```

Comment: That's more likely the answer I was looking for, thank you !