# Fastest way to search several strings in a string

Tags: java

Below is my code to find the occurrences of all the substrings in a given single string

```java
public static void main(String... args) {
    String fullString = "one is a good one. two is ok. three is three. four is four. five is not four";
    String[] severalStringArray = { "one", "two", "three", "four" };
    Map<String, Integer> countMap = countWords(fullString, severalStringArray);
}

public static Map<String, Integer> countWords(String fullString, String[] severalStringArray) {
    Map<String, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<>();

    for (String searchString : severalStringArray) {
        if (countMap.containsKey(searchString)) {
            int searchCount = countMatchesInString(fullString, searchString);
            countMap.put(searchString, countMap.get(searchString) + searchCount);
        } else
            countMap.put(searchString, countMatchesInString(fullString, searchString));
    }

    return countMap;
}

private static int countMatchesInString(String fullString, String subString) {
    int count = 0;
    int pos = fullString.indexOf(subString);
    while (pos > -1) {
        count++;
        pos = fullString.indexOf(subString, pos + 1);
    }
    return count;
}
```

Assume the full string might be a full file read as a string. Is the above is the efficient way of search or any other better way or fastest way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: You can look for `Trie` data structure to reduce time complexity

Comment: For string matching you can use Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm .

Comment: To be clear, the question you asked is about *counting* the number of times multiple strings appear in another string.  This means that simple solutions involving regexes, etcetera do not work.

Comment: Also ... beware of the case where the search strings overlap; e.g.  `{"one","onerous"}`.  This pretty much precludes using a regex with alternates.

Comment: @Deepeshkumar We need a example with the code snippet. Algorithm is too complex for a developer to understand and implement. If you share an example it would be great to comprehend or understand.

Comment: @integspecialist Yes you are right. I am posting the link to the code for the algorithm, the way I understood and modified and implemented. Link :
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/265575/175198

Answer (score 3):

You could just form a regex alternation of words to search, and then do a single search against that regex:

```java
public static int matchesInString(String fullString, String regex) {
    int count = 0;

    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = r.matcher(fullString);

    while (m.find())
        ++count;

    return count;
}

String fullString = "one is a good one. two is ok. three is three. four is four. five is not four";
String[] severalStringArray = { "one", "two", "three", "four" };
String regex = "\\b(?:" + String.join("|", severalStringArray) + ")\\b";

int count = matchesInString(fullString, regex);
System.out.println("There were " + count + " matches in the input");
```

This prints:

> There were 8 matches in the input

Note that the regex pattern used in the above example was:

```regex
\b(?:one|two|three|four)\b
```

Comment: i tried Regex and Pattern and found to be slow when working on huge file string. Did you get the speed when dealing with large file as well ?

Comment: The question is whether indexOf or Regex or contains - which one searches fast in java in huge string should be explored or verified.

Answer (score 1):

## Regular expressions

Your problem can be solved using *regex* (regular expressions). Regular expressions are a tool that help you matching patterns in strings. This pattern can be a word or can be a set of chars.

## Regular expressions in Java

In Java there are two Objects helping you with regular expressions: `Pattern` and `Matcher`.

Below you can see an example for searching if the word *stackoverflow* exists in the string *stackoverflowXstackoverflowXXXstackoverflowXX* in Java.

```
String pattern = "stackoverflow";
String stringToExamine = "stackoverflowXstackoverflowXXXstackoverflowXX";

Pattern patternObj = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher matcherObj = patternObj.matcher(stringToExamine);
```

### Counting how many occurrencies of a word in a given string

As written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378451/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-matches-for-a-regex) you have different solution based on your Java version:

> #### Java 9+
>
> ```
> long matches = matcherObj.results().count();
> ```
>
> #### Older Java versions
>
> ```
> int count = 0;
> while (matcherObj.find())
>     count++;
> ```

## Regular expressions in your problem

You use a method for calculating how many times a word is occurring in a text (a string), and you can modify it like this:

### Java 9+

```
public static int matchesInString(String fullString, String pattern)
{
    Pattern patternObj = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher matcherObj = patternObj.matcher(fullString);
    
    return matcherObj.results().count();
}
```

### Older Java versions

```
public static int matchesInString(String fullString, String pattern)
{
    int count = 0;

    Pattern patternObj = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher matcherObj = patternObj.matcher(fullString);
    
    while (matcherObj.find())
        count++;
        
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the fastest way is to scan the string first and count all existed words and save it into `Map`. Then select required words only.

Just be simple! The `regular expression` is too complicated and not efficient for this simple task. Let's solve it with a hummer!

```java
public static void main(String... args) {
    String str = "one is a good one. two is ok. three is three. four is four. five is not four";
    Set<String> words = Set.of("one", "two", "three", "four");
    Map<String, Integer> map = countWords(str, words);
}

public static Map<String, Integer> countWords(String str, Set<String> words) {
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; j <= str.length(); j++) {
        char ch = j == str.length() ? '\0' : str.charAt(j);

        if (j == str.length() || !isWordSymbol(ch)) {
            String word = str.substring(i, j);

            if (!word.isEmpty() && words.contains(word))
                map.put(word, map.getOrDefault(word, 0) + 1);

            i = j + 1;
        }
    }

    return map;
}

private static boolean isWordSymbol(char ch) {
    return Character.isLetter(ch) || ch == '-' || ch == '_';
}
```

Comment: Is creating a substring will not create an immutable object? Does it would be really performance better compared to indexOf? What are the issue the above solves instead of going for indexOf

Comment: `regexp` is too complicated. `indexOf(char)` I think is not fit, because you could have many letters and many whitespace characters.

Answer (score 0):

An implementation of the Trie tree that someone commented on. I don't know if it's fast or not.

```
static class Trie {

    static final long INC_NODE_NO = 1L << Integer.SIZE;

    private long nextNodeNo = 0;
    private Node root = new Node();
    private final Map<Long, Node> nodes = new HashMap<>();

    public void put(String word) {
        Node node = root;
        for (int i = 0, len = word.length(); i < len; ++i)
            node = node.put(word.charAt(i));
        node.data = word;
    }

    public List<String> findPrefix(String text, int start) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        Node node = root;
        for (int i = start, length = text.length(); i < length; ++i) {
            if ((node = node.get(text.charAt(i))) == null)
                break;
            String v = node.data;
            if (v != null)
                result.add(v);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public Map<String, Integer> find(String text) {
        Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0, length = text.length(); i < length; ++i)
            for (String w : findPrefix(text, i))
                result.compute(w, (k, v) -> v == null ? 1 : v + 1);
        return result;
    }

    class Node {
        final long no;
        String data;

        Node() {
            this.no = nextNodeNo;
            nextNodeNo += INC_NODE_NO;
        }

        Node get(int key) {
            return nodes.get(no | key);
        }

        Node put(int key) {
            return nodes.computeIfAbsent(no | key, k -> new Node());
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    String fullString = "one is a good one. two is ok. three is three. four is four. five is not four";
    String[] severalStringArray = { "one", "two", "three", "four" };
    Trie trie = new Trie();
    for (String word : severalStringArray)
        trie.put(word);
    Map<String, Integer> count = trie.find(fullString);
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

output:

```
{four=3, one=2, three=2, two=1}
```